# Understanding Variable Accessibility in Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, atomic

I'm trying to get a better understanding of accessing variables in threads. After doing a little bit of research, I found a lot of info about `atomic`, which works great! I've come to a stand-still, though, and would like some help moving forward.

### Set Up:

- I have two classes - one class reads from a text file to grab information from last launch and other information I need for every launch. This is in a separate class just for organization. The info read is stored in atomic variables.
- The other class has **all** of my functions. This includes ones where it reads the variables used to store information that was from the information file. Simply put, this class inherits the first class the variables that hold that info file.
- The main function creates class objects **at the very beginning** of the code together because I need the functions within the classes for the other parts of the program. After the initial set up (including reading that info file), it creates threads from the second class functions that need to run for the rest of the program

### Question:

Why can the threads with functions from the second class not read the information it inherited from the first class?

- I'm reading long before the threads are created. Maybe because the second class is inheriting the original variables (which were all initialized as 0) because I declared it before I did the read info file function?
- The variables in the main function read fine.

.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> timeToClose = false;

class first {
public:
    std::atomic<int> primary;
    void readFile() {
        primary = 1;
    }
    first() {
        primary = 0;
    }
};

class second: first {
public:
    void actionPrimary() {
        while (!timeToClose) {
            if (primary) {
                std::cout << "We ARE doing stuff here!\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
            } else {
                std::cout << "We AREN'T doing stuff here!\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    first f;
    second s;
    f.readFile();
    std::thread threadActionPrimary([&s]() {
        s.actionPrimary();
    });
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1)) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    timeToClose = true;
    threadActionPrimary.join();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Editing to bump :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I've looked at dozens of other threads (which were also on stack overflow) but they all only vaguely related. I thought I'd make my own question. I've tried changing how my variables are read, what my variable datatypes are, how they are stored, how the threads are created and which formats (like lambda and whatnot), different thread inheritance, etc. Sorry if the question doesn't seem very informative, I'll add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: After you've stored the file info in variables, will those variables be modified ?

Comment: Please do so if you can show the community what you want to do with the proper code this question will be answered accordingly.

Comment: @LWimsey Some will, some won't.

Comment: @Sand Done : -)

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got your intention. In `main()`, you have one instance `first f;` and another `second s;`. Then you call `f.readfile();`. Then you start a thread with reference to `s`. Do you expect that `s` contains the data of `f`? Though `s` is of class `second` which is inherited from `first` (the class of `f`) each instance has its own data. `std::atomic<>` doesn't change this. If you make `first::primary` a **`static`** member _then_ it would change.

Comment: Btw. `first() { primary = 0; }` is bad style. Better: `first(): primary(0) { }`. The first version does implicit member construction and then assignment. The latter does explicit member construction - no assignment needed. In this case, the difference (in code) is probably minimal but you should use the latter style in general...

Comment: I'll keep that style in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

> When does items in thread a become visible to thread b.

This is related to [cppreference : memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).  A change is visible to a second thread.

- thread A wrote to an atomic value (using `std::atomic`)
- thread B read the atomic value (using `std::atomic` )

There are some more complex versions which relate to synchronization.

- thread A writes some data.
- thread A uses a mutex or writes to std::atomic << sync.
- thread B uses mutex or reads from std::atomic
- thread B can see all the memory changes from thread A up to the point it synchronized.

What is actually happening in this case, is instance data in a class variable.

```
class MyBase {
    public:
       int BaseValue;
       MyBase() : BaseValue(10);
       void setValue( int v ) {
           BaseValue = v;
       }
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase {
      MyDerived() {}
};

 MyBase base;
 base.setValue( 12 );
 MyDerived derived;
 // derived.BaseValue = 10;
 // base.BaseValue = 12;  <<<< There are 2 different instances of the member BaseValue.
```

### Update

Each time you create a variable;

```
int i = 5;
int j = 10;
```

You create a new 'container' of things.  If you want the two threads to communicate using one of the classes (`second`?) you need to create a single container, then the data should be visible.

However to get it to work correctly, you need to have some form of synchronization between the 2 threads.

```
int main() {
    second s;
    s.readFile();
    std::thread threadActionPrimary([&s]() { // this acts as a synchronization point, so the thread sees all the changes to s that happened before this line.
        s.actionPrimary();
    });
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1)) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    timeToClose = true;
    threadActionPrimary.join();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Right, so this explains it, but what can I do to actually make the instances synchronize?

Comment: Also, seems like your input "v" is doing nothing. BaseValue = 5 after running setValue