# Understanding Class Variable Accessibility in Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, inheritance, atomic

I'm trying to get a better understanding of accessing variables in threads. After doing a little bit of research, I found a lot of info about `atomic`, which works great! I've come to a stand-still, though, and would like some help moving forward.

### Set Up:

- I have two classes - one class reads from a text file to grab information from last launch and other information I need for every launch. This is in a separate class just for organization. The info read is stored in atomic variables.
- The other class has **all** of my functions. This includes ones where it reads the variables used to store information that was from the information file. Simply put, this class inherits the first class the variables that hold that info file.
- The main function creates class objects **at the very beginning** of the code together because I need the functions within the classes for the other parts of the program. After the initial set up (including reading that info file), it creates threads from the second class functions that need to run for the rest of the program

### Question:

Why can the threads with functions from the second class not read the information it inherited from the first class?

- I'm reading long before the threads are created. Maybe because the second class is inheriting the original variables (which were all initialized as 0) because I declared it before I did the read info file function?
- The variables in the main function read fine.

.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> timeToClose = false;

class first {
public:
    std::atomic<int> primary;
    void readFile() {
        primary = 1;
    }
    first() {
        primary = 0;
    }
};

class second: first {
public:
    void actionPrimary() {
        while (!timeToClose) {
            if (primary) {
                std::cout << "We ARE doing stuff here!\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
            } else {
                std::cout << "We AREN'T doing stuff here!\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    first f;
    second s;
    f.readFile();
    std::thread threadActionPrimary([&s]() {
        s.actionPrimary();
    });
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1)) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    timeToClose = true;
    threadActionPrimary.join();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

It's my understanding that the class that derives has a separate instance of the variable, so I'm trying to figure out what I can do to get around this and make sure they're synchronized.

Should I just combine all my classes since they're codependent?

Comment: You have two objects of type `first` in your program - a most-derived one named `f`, and the base class subobject of `s`. They are two separate, unrelated instances, each with its own set of member variables. `f.primary` has nothing whatsoever to do with `s.primary`. All this is unrelated to threads, it's OOP 101.

Comment: So what can I do to ensure these variables are synchronized?

Comment: You don't. Drop `f`, call `s.readFile()` instead.

Comment: will the constructor still run if I dont create the first class object?

Comment: But you do. When you create an instance of `second`, you also necessarily create an instance of `first` - its base class subobject. [`second` is-a `first`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) - that's what inheritance is all about.

Comment: damn, that'll require me to rewrite almost all of my code to keep it in scope of is-a input obj. is there no alternative to ensure that the variables are synced?

Comment: Why do you think the two objects you created are related by any means?

Comment: When you create a derived class object it inherits base class properties variables and methods of its own.

Comment: but it doesn't directly inherit them, huh? so in other words I'd need to merge all these classes if I want there to be once instance of each variable. that, or i'd have to change every line of code that inherits that info to be object pointed

Comment: You may be better off creating a singleton object that each of the other objects reference.

Comment: got some example code I can follow? also please post it as an answer. if it works i'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Variable Accessibility in Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337788/understanding-variable-accessibility-in-threads)

Comment: @LWimsey that was my question